# Finding the correct SAML Identity provider to authenticate a user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, saml, saml-2.0, google-identity

I am trying to configure **Google Cloud Identity Platform** to use multiple SAML identity providers. Still, I'm stuck at the point of selecting the right IdP for every person attempting to log in.

I have read about **[SAML v2 IDP Discovery Service](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19854-01/819-5209/gbtfd/index.html)** but I don't really understand how it works since I am a novice in SAML.

So does it have to be a programmatic solution or does **GCIP** have something that I can configure to automatically select the right IdP for each user?

If it has to be a programmatic solution can someone point me to a good explanation of **SAML v2 IDP Discovery Service**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up Google Cloud Identity Platform (GCIP) to automatically select the appropriate identity provider (IdP) for each user. A protocol known as SAML v2 IDP Discovery Service enables users to select their IdP from a drop-down menu. Its purpose is to make it unnecessary for users to remember which IdP they should use.

You will need to configure the service in your GCIP project in order to put this into action. Each provider's metadata and any additional parameters that the IdP may require must be provided to the IdP. The user will be able to select their IdP from a drop-down menu on their login page following the completion of the configuration. The official [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml) provides additional details on how to use SAML v2 IDP Discovery Service.

Refer to this how to enable [multi-tenancy](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart) for Identity Platform and Creating a [sign-in page for multiple tenants](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-ui)

Comment: But this isn't really automatic, my target users are students and I don't think that they know which IdP their Uni works with, with the solution you discussed each user should know which IdP to pick from the drop-down menu, is there another way to know the IdP that this user belongs to automatically?

Comment: You can use the OAuth2 protocol and the OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol to authenticate users and determine which IdP they belong to. OAuth2 and OIDC are both open standards that allow applications to request and obtain identity information about users. When a user attempts to log in to your application, you can use OAuth2 and OIDC to send a request to the user's IdP, which will return identity details about the user, such as their username, email address, and any other relevant information.

Comment: This information can then be used to determine which IdP the user belongs to and present them with the appropriate drop-down menu.